# problem with R 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Tags: r, function, null

I´ve created this function:

```
vlw=function(x,y)
{
for(i in 0:20){
if((i>=1)&(i<=4)|(i>=6)&(i<=9)|(i>=11)&(i<=14)|(i>=16)&(i<=19))
{
  next()
}
print(ifelse((x<i)&(y<i)|(x>(i+5))&(y>(i+5)),0,ifelse((x<i)&(y<(i+5)),(y-i)/5,ifelse((x<(i+5))&(y>(i+5)),(i+5-x)/5,ifelse((x>i)&(y<(i+5)),(y-x)/5,1)))))
  }
}
```

If I I use this imputs:

```
iv=c(-1,-2,4,9,10,5,-1)
fv=c(3,-1,6,10,11,10,8)
```

my result is:

```
[1] 0.6 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.2
[1] 0.0 0.0 0.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.6
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The problem is that I would like to creat a matrix from this result, but when I put:

```
exp4=as.matrix(vlw(iv,fv),5,7)
```

I read this error:

Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL

Do you know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler example that explains the issue more clearly:

```
f = function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    if (i==2) next()
    print (i)
  }
}

x = f()
# [1] 1

x
# NULL
```

Essentially, the function will return whatever expression was last evaluated.  In this case `next()`.  The value returned by `next` is `NULL`.  Therefore when you assign the result of `f()`, it will have the value `NULL`.

Rather than using `print` inside your function, you should instead fill a vector with the values you are printing, and return this vector.

Like this:

```
vlw=function(x,y)
{
  output=c()
  for(i in 0:20) {
    if((i>=1)&(i<=4)|(i>=6)&(i<=9)|(i>=11)&(i<=14)|(i>=16)&(i<=19))
    {
      next()
    }
    output =c(output,
      ifelse((x<i)&(y<i)|(x>(i+5))&(y>(i+5)),0,ifelse((x<i)&(y<(i+5)),(y-i)/5,ifelse((x<(i+5))&(y>(i+5)),(i+5-x)/5,ifelse((x>i)&(y<(i+5)),(y-x)/5,1))))
      )
  }
  return(output)
}


exp4 = matrix(vlw(iv,fv),5,7)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]  0.6  1.0  1.0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]  0.0  1.2  1.0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]  0.2  0.0  1.0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.6    1    0    0    0
#[5,]  0.0  0.2  0.0    0    0    0    0
```